# Istio samples application "ensure CRDs are installed first"

Tags: kubernetes, istio

**Steps:**

Install istio using istioctl

[image: istioctl run]

Get crds:

[image]
Run sample application
https://istio.io/latest/docs/examples/bookinfo/

**Expected:**

Sample application is created

**Actual**:

no matches for kind "Gateway" in version "gateway.networking.k8s.io/v1beta1"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the CRDs for Kubernetes Gateway API installed.

Note the difference in the CRD names:

`gateways.networking.istio.io`
`gateway.networking.k8s.io/v1beta1`

Install the Kubernetes Gateway API ([check here](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/gateway-api/)), and you'll be good.